# Can data be uploaded to iCloud without your consent?

Tags: ios

I have been a loyal iPhone user for years. I did have two Apple IDs previously. The other one has already been deleted by Apple formally.

The current Apple ID I am using was set up years ago when you had the option of opting out from iCloud features. So basically the iCloud was never set up at the first place with regard to this ID. Under my ID profile in the setting, the iCloud status was off.

[image]

So can I confirm if my data of phone were all kept locally on my device without being uploading to any cloud own by Apple without my knowledge?

I am not using Safari for either but Firefox or Google Chrome. Even if you have an iCloud activated, would the data of these 3rd party apps also be transmitted to Apple Servers through iCloud?

Comment: From a pure technical point of view there is no human consent needed in order to transfer some data. This  means that the question is a legal one and therefore off-topic. Please try [law.se].

Answer (score 1):

*theoretically you can't confirm. Apple can lie to you. But you got no reason to think they will.*

The real answer is for data linked to your Apple ID **you can confirm**. By going to the [Apple privacy portal](https://privacy.apple.com). You can request to download every single bit of data they got on you. And see for yourself.

---

This includes:

> - Apple Media Services information    Includes App Store, iTunes Store, Apple Books, Apple Music, Podcasts activity
> - Apple ID account and device information
> - Apple Online and Retail Stores activity  Show more Apple Online and Retail Stores activity
> - Apple Pay activity
> - AppleCare support history, repair requests, and more Show more    AppleCare support history, repair requests, and more
> - Game Center activity
> - iCloud Bookmarks and reading list
> - iCloud Calendars and Reminders
> - iCloud Contacts
> - iCloud Notes
> - Maps Report an Issue
> - Marketing communications, downloads, and other activity
> - iCloud Drive files and documents
> - iCloud Mail
> - iCloud Photos
> - Other data

No need to download everything. Just what you want to view.

Comment: You could confirm - keeping the phone on a wi-fi network and sniffing packets to look for requests to Apple (though you probably wouldn't be able to tell WHAT is sent you could rule out certain requests by statistical analysis)

Comment: @LTPCGO that can only work for future data unless you have some logs of past traffic somewhere.

Comment: true, in this specific case, but worth pointing out for anyone coming across this who may be worried about the same thing